# PHP IF si se dan dos condiciones

Tags: php

Quiero que un menú desplegable solo puedan verse los enlaces a los sitios a los cuales se tenga permiso. Para ello le aplico una variable con la función `SESSION` y si es un nivel u otro le indico que pueda ver o no ver el menú.

Ahora mismo tengo dos ejemplos pero ninguno de ellos me funciona solo logro hacer que funcione aplicándole una única condición en el `IF` pero claro, necesito varias a la vez por que tengo 5 niveles de usuario.

```
<?php
          if (!isset($_SESSION["privilegio"]) || $_SESSION["privilegio"] == 5 and $_SESSION["privilegio"] == 3) {
            echo '<li><a href="../categoria/index.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Tabla Categorías</a></li>';
            echo '<li><a href="../subcategoria/index.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Tabla Subcategorías</a></li>';
            echo '<li><a href="../tipodocumentos/index.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Tabla Tipo de Documentos</a></li>';
          }
        ?>
```

Y esta es la otra:

```
<?php
          if (!isset($_SESSION["privilegio"]) || $_SESSION["privilegio"] == 5 and == 3) {
            echo '<li><a href="../categoria/index.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Tabla Categorías</a></li>';
            echo '<li><a href="../subcategoria/index.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Tabla Subcategorías</a></li>';
            echo '<li><a href="../tipodocumentos/index.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Tabla Tipo de Documentos</a></li>';
          }
        ?>
```

Comment: if ( condicion1 && condicion2){ ... }

Comment: perfecto estaba casí era los "&&", pongo la solución debajo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta usar el mismo tipo de operadores, si usas "and" deberías usar "or" y si prefieres usar "||" deberías usar "&&".

No se exactamente la diferencia, pero se que la hay. Para más información [preferencias de los operadores en php](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.precedence.php)

También te aconsejaría utilizar "(" y ")" a mi al principio me ayudaba a aclararme que condiciones se ejecutaban primero, y que lo hicieran como yo quisiera.

De todos modos, no le encuentro mucha lógica, estas indicando que privilegio == 5 y con un "and" le estas diciendo que tiene que ser == 3. No creo que nunca se cumpla este if. (Sin parenteresis el && tendrá preferencia sobre el || por lo que primero compara que sea == 5 Y == 3

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["privilegio"]) || $_SESSION["privilegio"] == 5 && $_SESSION["privilegio"] == 3)
```

Prueba con:

```
if (isset($_SESSION["privilegio"]) && ($_SESSION["privilegio"] == 5) || $_SESSION["privilegio"] == 3))
```

Con esto primero compruebas con isset que este declarada la variable, y luego que sea uno de los siguientes permisos.

Un saludo. Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (isset($_SESSION["privilegio"]) && $_SESSION["privilegio"] == 5 || $_SESSION["privilegio"] == 4)
```

El usuario `aldanux`casí lo había puesot bien, pero eran los `&`debido a que la condición no se tiene que dar a la vez si no que un usuario entra con us nivle no con dos, entonces la solución era cambiar estos `&`por `|`.

Comment: Bien!! +1.. me equivoque escribiendo lo en el comentario... :)